# How to read alert message content in android using appium?

Tags: appium

currently I am using following method to read the alert message content but it throws error saying not yet implemented. What is the alternative method to achieve this?

driver1.switchTo().alert().getText();

Error :org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Not yet implemented. Please help us: http://appium.io/get-involved.html (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In appium there is no need to use the switchto.alert method to capture the alert messages. Alert messages in mobile are actually in the native context and you have to switch to the native context to access the alert buttons/text.

```
driver1.context("NATIVE_APP");
```

After that you can capture the alert as an native element and fire any action upon it. Ex :

```
driver1.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.Button[@text='Yes']")).click();
```